# infinite scrolling without button with python dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash, infinite-scroll

As discussed [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/add-dynamic-content-to-a-div/22233), the following code can simulate infinite scrolling with a button at the end of the page

```
app.layout=html.Div(
    id='output',
    children=[
        html.Div("Thing 1")
    ],
    html.Button("Load more",id='load-new-content',n_clicks=0)
)

@app.callback(
    Output('output','children'),
    [Input('load-new-content','n_clicks')],
    [State('output','children')])
def more_output(n_clicks,old_output):
    if n_clicks==0:
        raise PreventUpdate
    return old_output + [html.Div('Thing {}'.format(n_clicks))]
```

Is there a way to achieve the same without a button?

Is it possible to trigger the same callback on an event like scrolling to the bottom of the page?

Preferably in `python` and `dash`, without going into Java Scripting

Answer (score 1):

Probably not without getting into some JS, unless you can find a custom component that someone created which is already available.

Essentially, you need a way to trigger a Dash callback with something like a scroll action, or the vertical scroll hitting the bottom. Neither of those things is connected to Dash through the core component library (`dcc`). That means a custom component that can trigger a callback based on listening to an event like that would be required.